# Unable to add cookie to browser context for testing app

Tags: next.js, prisma, playwright, next-auth

**Context:**

- Playwright Version: 1.31.1
- Operating System: Linux
- Node.js version: v18.13.0
- Browser: Chromium
- Extra: Using next auth

**Code Snippet**

`playwright.config.ts`

```js
import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test";

export default defineConfig({
  testDir: "./tests",
  timeout: 30 * 1000,
  expect: {
    timeout: 5000,
  },
  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  reporter: "html",
  use: {
    actionTimeout: 0,
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
    trace: "on-first-retry",
    storageState: "./playwright/storageState.json",
  },
  globalSetup: "./playwright/globalSetup.ts",

  projects: [
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: { ...devices["Desktop Chrome"] },
    },
  ],
});
```

`globalSetup.ts`

```js
import prisma from "@db/prisma";

async function globalSetup() {
  const date = new Date();
  await prisma.user.upsert({
    where: {
      email: "e2e@e2e.com",
    },
    create: {
      name: "e2e",
      email: "e2e@e2e.com",
      sessions: {
        create: {
          expires: new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0),
          sessionToken: "04456e41-ec3b-4edf-92c1-48c14e57cacd2",
        },
      },
      accounts: {
        create: {
          type: "oauth",
          provider: "github",
          providerAccountId: "2222222",
          access_token: "ggg_zZl1pWIvKkf3UDynZ09zLvuyZsm1yC0YoRPt",
          token_type: "bearer",
          scope: "read:org,read:user,repo,user:email",
        },
      },
    },
    update: {},
  });
}

export default globalSetup;
```

`example.spec.ts`

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";
import { chromium } from "playwright";

test("that it can log in", async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext({ storageState: "playwright/storageState.json" });
  await context.addCookies([
    {
      name: "next-auth.session-token",
      value: "70cc2794-e2a8-420d-98d8-3b55b0395726",
      domain: "localhost",
      path: "/",
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "Lax",
      expires: 1661406204,
    },
  ]);
  context.storageState({ path: "playwright/storageState.json" });
  expect(await context.cookies()).toEqual([]); // this works, but it should not
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto("/");
  await page.getByText("Button text that only appears on the logged in page").click(); // this does not work, but it should
});
```

**Describe the bug**

I'm trying to write a test E2E my app which uses next-auth for auth. When I run ethe test a user with email `e2e@e2e.com` is created, however, the page in the test in not authenticated, i believe because the cookie is not being set.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why you set **storageState** twice, when you you have it in global config. And why you created new **browser** and **context**.

But `await context.cookies()` is `[]` because of expiration.

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";
import { chromium } from "@playwright/test";

test("that it can log in", async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  await context.addCookies([
    {
      name: "next-auth.session-token",
      value: "70cc2794-e2a8-420d-98d8-3b55b0395726",
      domain: "localhost",
      path: "/",
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "Lax",
    },
  ]);
  expect(await context.cookies()).toEqual([]);
});
```

throws

```
    Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  -  1
    + Received  + 12

    - Array []
    + Array [
    +   Object {
    +     "domain": "localhost",
```